# Use Explorer for deleting files/folders in Total Commander

Tags: windows, recycle-bin, total-commander

Putting `ExplorerForCopy=1` in the .ini file instructs Total Commander to use Explorer for copying of files, but is there a similar option to make it use Explorer for deleting files and folders?

I need this because currently [deleting folders is slow](https://superuser.com/questions/620813/why-is-deleting-files-to-recycle-bin-so-much-slower-than-when-using-shiftdel-wi/620818).

**Edit:** I'm asking about moving them to Recycle Bin (i.e. Del, not Shift+Del).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win95Delete=1

According to [This post](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=31293&view=next) anyway...